# How to darken a MaterialUI Avatar component image and put text on it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I'm using the Avatar component from Material UI. I'am also using Tailwind
I can simply put the `src` with the image url and it works

```html
<Avatar alt="Cindy Baker" src="https://mui.com/static/images/avatar/3.jpg" />
```

But I have a situation where I need to put an overlay on the image (make it darker) and need to put a white text like **+5**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ohycv7?file=Demo.tsx

Right now it looks like this

[image]

I need it to look something like

[image]

**EDIT**

with the help of gpt i came up with a close one
[image] but the text is also darkened now

```html
      <Avatar
        sx={{
          position: 'relative',
          filter: 'brightness(50%)',
          '&::before': {
            content: "'+2'",
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '50%',
            left: '50%',
            transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: '1.5rem', // Adjust the font size as needed
          },
        }}
        alt="Cindy Baker"
        src="https://mui.com/static/images/avatar/3.jpg"
      />
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @JaromandaX i did try `sx={{filter:brightness(50%)}}` as an avatar prop and that darkened the image. but how to add the text i do not know

Comment: Have you looked into [<Badge>](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/badge/)

Comment: @JaromandaX not sure how badge is applied to this tho. i also came up with something. edited question and sandbox

Comment: documentation of `<Avatar>` mentions it so ...

Comment: @JaromandaX i tried to use a badge too but it only has the 4 corners as positions. since i need this in the middle im bit stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use filter, just make the background of the "pseudo element" a semi-transparent black

```
<Avatar
        sx={{
          position: 'relative',
          // remove this 
          filter: 'brightness(50%)',
          */
          '&::before': {
            content: "'+2'",
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '50%',
            left: '50%',
            transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: '1.5rem', // Adjust the font size as needed

            // add these 2 lines
            padding:'100%', // add this
            background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',

          },
        }}
        alt="Cindy Baker"
        src="https://mui.com/static/images/avatar/3.jpg"
      />
```